# Moving group of files to another directory using the command "rename" with regular expressions

Tags: linux, bash, regular-expression, rename

I have some markdown files that I want to move to a different directory called "newDirectory2" within "newDirectory1".

These files contain the string "abc" or "ABC" or "Abc" somewhere in their titles

I tried the following command:

```
rename 's/newDirectory1\/newDirectory2\/$1/s' 's/(^.*[abc|ABC|Abc].*.md)/s'
```

But it doesn't work :/, what I'm doing it wrong? please help

Comment: You need to study Rename's syntax more carefully, for there are several mistakes in your attempt. Composing a minimal, reproducible example (with some sample files before/after the operation) is very helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overcomplicating the issue. A straightforward `mv` will achieve what you're asking,

```
mv *[Aa][Bb][Cc]* newDirectory1/newDirectory2
```